# ¿How to obtain an endpoint from an autoML that gives me the test result in probabilities instead of in binary classes in AzureMLStudio?

Tags: endpoint, azure-machine-learning-service, automl, azure-ai

I created a model in Azure ML through AutoML.

Then I selected the "best model":
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QEEt.png)

, then I selected the job that created that model:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5ctQ.png)
, and I finally deployed the model to a real-time endpoint:
[image(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZX1c.png)

But when I test the model it returns to me the binary class of the test but not the probability of belonging to this class.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auTwZ.png)

I know that for this I have to modify the way it predicts the values, I know that I need to use the predict_proba function.But this automated process of using the best automl model does not allow me to choose the way to obtain the output or at least I do not know it.

I have tried downloading the model once registered and modifying the score.py script and uploading the model again in custom format, but I don't understand how to then upload the environment .yml part. I have also tried to do the entire process only with python from notebooks and I can't.

Does anyone know a simple idea to get the probability in the inferences made on the endpoint instead of a binary class as a result? eternally grateful, even accurate documentation would be welcome, I think I have read it all already

Does anyone know a simple idea to get the probability in the inferences made on the endpoint instead of a binary class as a result? eternally grateful, even accurate documentation would be welcome, I think I have read it all already

Comment: Hey Chris, I am having the exact same problem where I am getting 0 or 1 for a binary classification model I trained ((using Azure auto ML)) but i want the probabilities instead. Did you get anywhere with this? From my reading it looks like we need to do a custom deploy with a custom scoring script...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have deployed an endpoint using this sample [notebook.](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/automated-machine-learning/classification-bank-marketing-all-features/auto-ml-classification-bank-marketing-all-features.ipynb)

As the score.py contains method in input schema shown below,
[image]

You can pass method `predict_proba` along with your data to get probabilities.
[image]

Comment: ¿Would you be so kind to paste the entire json code example? thank you in advance.